# Show a linear $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ function is continous

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to get a sold foundation on my understanding of topological continuity, so I want to make sure I can accurately prove some simple examples.

> Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x) = (a x , b x)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Using the $\varepsilon, \delta$ definition of continuous.

Finding $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ will show that such a $\delta$ exists. My assertion is that:
$$ \delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{|a+b|}$$
$$d_2= |f(x) - f(y)|= |ax - ay| + |bx-by|= |a(x - y)| + |b(x-y)|= |a+b||x-y|$$
$$d_1=|x-y|$$
If $d_1 < \delta$ then $|x-y|<\delta$. Let $c_1$ be a slack variable such that $c_1>0$. Thus, $|x-y|=\delta-c_1$.

Next I will show that if the above line is true then , $d_2 < \varepsilon$

Subbing "$|x-y|=\delta-c_1$" into " $d_2=|a+b||x-y|$", we have
$$d_2=|a+b|(\delta-c_1)$$ 
Next sub in the asserted $\delta$
$$d_2=|a+b|(\frac{\varepsilon}{|a+b|}-c_1)$$ 
$$d_2=|a+b|\frac{\varepsilon}{|a+b|}-|a+b|c_1$$ 
$$d_2=\varepsilon-|a+b|c_1$$ 
The above expression must be less than $\varepsilon$
$$\varepsilon-|a+b|c_1<\varepsilon$$
Subtracting $\varepsilon$ from both sides, and multiplying by -1 we have,
$$|a+b|c_1>0$$ 
$|a+b|$ and $c_1$ are both positive, and the product of positives is always positive.Therefore, if $a \neq -b$ then $\delta$ defined above will work, and if $a=-b$ then delta can be any positive number.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: why are you using that metric for $\mathbb {R}^2$ ? I mean why isn't $d_2= \sqrt {|ax - ay|^2 + |bx-by|^2}$ ?

Comment: Your proof cannot be valid because when $a = -b$, it is *not* true that $\delta$ can be any positive number.  That would mean $(ax_1,-ax_1)$ and $(ax_2, -ax_2)$ are only $\epsilon$ apart no matter how far apart $x_1$ and $x_2$ are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More succinct may be the following.

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since
$$
|(ax,bx) - (ac,bc)| = |(a(x-c), b(x-c))| = (a^{2}+b^{2})(x-c)^{2} < \varepsilon
$$
if $|x-c| < \sqrt{\varepsilon/(a^{2}+b^{2})}$,
so $\delta := \sqrt{\varepsilon/(a^{2}+b^{2})}$ is such that
$|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$ for all $|x-c| < \delta$.

Answer (score 2):

I lost you at

> $$d_2= |f(x) - f(y)|= |ax - ay| + |bx-by|= |a(x - y)| + |b(x-y)|= |a+b||x-y|$$

Where is the justification for this? How is $|f(x)-f(y)|$ equal to $|ax-ay| + |bx-by|$? Since $f(x)-f(y) = (ax-ay, bx-by)$, are you using a non-Euclidean metric for $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: My book says the <b>Euclidean metric</b> is $d=|x-y|$. So I took that as meaning $d=|(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)| = |x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|. $ But now I'm realizing $d=(|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|)$ and $d^2 =(|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|).(|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|)= (x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2$.I see my mistake.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky The euclidean metric on $\mathbb R$, yes. But that is the distance between $x$ and $y$ where $x,y$ are **numbers**. In your case, $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are **vectors**.

Comment: $d=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2| $, is still a proper metric, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky It is a metric, sure, but it is non-standard and I doubt it is what the question wants you to use.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky Also, note that even if it was the correct metric, you wrote $|a(x-y)| + |b(x-y)| = |a+b||x-y|$ which is not true (set $x=1, y=0, a=1, b=-1$ to see the counter-example).